# How to grid the data without the interpolation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to grid the data in 3D array.
Ex: I have 4 parameters ls( dat_ls) , longitude (dat_longi),sza (dat_sza), and temperature. I need to grid array Temperature (36 (ls)X 36 (longitude)X 18 (sza)).

I have written the following code but it is taking too much time. please, suggest is there any faster method to work with.

```
w1=np.arange(0,360,10)
w2=np.arange(5,365,10)    

# w1 and w2 are the ls value range

# to creat the grid
deg= np.arange(0,370,10)    
szdeg=np.arange(0,190,10)  
         

val33=[]
for q in range(len(w1)):
    val22=[]
    for u1 in range(len(dat_ls)):
        if w2[q] >= dat_ls[u1] >= w1[q]:  # this gives value between two range of ls
               
            val2=[]                
            for h in range(len(deg)-1):
                val1=[]
                for h1 in range(len(szdeg)-1):
                    val=[]
                    if ((deg[h+1] >= dat_longi[u1] >= deg[h]) and (szdeg[h1+1] >= dat_sza[u1] >= szdeg[h1])):  
                            val.append(np.array(temperature[u1]).ravel()) # u1 corresponds to points value (index) the ls,longi,sza.
                    val1.append(np.array(np.nanmean(val)))        
                val2.append(val1)            
        val22.append(val2)
    val33.append(val22)
```

val33 is array of temperature value with a grid of (36(ls),36(longitude),18(sza))

Thank you

Comment: You state in your explanation that you have 4 parameters ls, longitude, sza, & temperature.  Yet your code doesn't show these same parameters, can you clarify which of the 4 variables w1, w2, deg, & sza correlate to each of your parameters?  Also, can you provide what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: I have shown all the four values, ls, longitude,sza, and temperature. w1,w2 are used to set the beginning ls range for the grid. I am looking for a grid of temperature values that corresponds to each (ls,longi,sza).